# How to Solve this Polynomial Problem?

Tags: polynomials

If $2x^3 +Mx^2 +Nx +6$ is divisible by both $x-1$ and $x+2$, find the values of $M$ and $N$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: A polynomial $P(x)$ is divisible by $x-a$ if and only if $a$ is a root of $P(x)$, that is $P(a)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$2x^3 +Mx^2 +Nx +6=(ax+b)(x-1)(x+2)= a x^3  + (a+b) x^2 +(b - 2 a) x - 2 b$$
$$\begin{align}-2b&=6\Rightarrow b=-3\\a&=2\Rightarrow M=a+b\Rightarrow \color{red}{M=-1}\\N&=b-2a\Rightarrow\color{red}{N=-7}\end{align}$$

and the third root is $$x=\frac{-b}{a}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: What is the reason that you use ax+b?

Comment: @JonMarcTorred The polynomial is of degree three (equivalent to the product of three terms of degree one). You have two terms of degree one already. So we need one more term of degree one which in general is $ax+b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x) = 2x^3 + Mx^2 + Nx + 6$,
    $f(x) = x-1$
    $g(x) = x+2$

Now, $f(x)|p(x)$ and $g(x)|p(x)$.
This implies that, $1$ and $-2$ are the zeros of $p(x)$.
Thus, $p(1) = p(-2) = 0$
Now, 
$p(1) = 2 + M+N+6 = 0$
After solving we get (eq 1) $$M+N = -8$$
Similarly, $p(-2)  = -16+4M-2N+6 = 0$
After solving, we get (eq 2)$$2M-N=5$$

Adding equation 1 and 2 we get:
$M+N+2M-N=-8+5$
$3M=-3$
$M=-1$

Since $M=-1$, therefore from eq 1, $N=-7$.

Comment: What is the reason that you added both equation 1and 2?

Comment: Well, you know that you have to eliminate one variable out of the two to make it in linear form so you can either add or subtract the two equations so that one variable gets eliminated. If it doesn't work then you've to use substitution method.